# Sign up with email code verification with django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Can you guys tell me how to add a functionality in our website, when a user come to our site and fill sign up form and then click on sign up button than an email sent to his/her email account with a verification code. which he copy and paste on verification code template if code is same than let him log in otherwise send code again. If you know how to do this then tell me or If you know that if i can get help related to this than refer me. I shall be very thankful to you.

Well I already made forget password with email verification and already made sign up and login for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official python document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for how to send emails with python.